# ER Diagram with ERWin 3.5

Tags: database-design, erwin

I started my course and have been working on the ER diagram.

Instructions provided are

---

Minimum requirements and business rules for the College database 
a) The college is organized into Departments.
- Each department has a number, name, location, phone number, budget, and an employee who manages the department.
- Keep track of the start date of the each department manager.
b) Employees work for a department and each employee works for a designated project.
- Each employee has a number, last name, first name, address, city, phone number, rank and salary.
c) Faculty members work for a department.
- Each faculty has a number, last name, first name, address, gender, birth date, area of expertise, and salary.
- Each faculty works for one department but may work on several research projects. 
d) Each department controls several research Projects.
- Each project has a name, number, duration (in months), budget, and a primary investigator. 
e) Each faculty teaches several Courses.
- For each course, keep the course name, number, credit hours, type (lecture, lab, distance learning, etc.), and cost per credit hour.
- A course can be offered by different faculty members.

---

This is what I have done using ERWin 3.5
[image: This is what I have done for now]

I am stuck and know that this diagram is wrong.
Can someone help me with this please.
Thanks in advance